# How to create free-standing Solr document post URL?

Tags: r, solr, rcurl

Is it possible to create a complete, free-standing url that will post a new document to solr?  I looked at the log after I successfully posted through the documents tab on the Solr Admin interface, but I haven't been able to get request logging to work yet.

I'm trying to diagnose an error I'm getting from the R document positing function at https://github.com/datadolphyn/R/blob/master/r_solr_integration.R

Comment: not sure I understand the question, but i do have a Solr R client here https://github.com/ropensci/solr FWIW

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, your client looks great and I'll probably try it tomorrow.  But it doesn't facilitate posting new documents, does it?

Comment: No, just reads for now. I'll work on adding writing functionality soon (creating/editing/deleting)

Comment: You need to clarify the question a bit - exactly what do you need? The URL to POST an update to Solr is usually (depending on configuration, but people usually don't change this) http://host:port/solr/<corename>/update.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh .  Sorry, I'm probably using the wrong terms here:  what would the command and payload part of the URL be.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh .  What would the command and payload part of the URL be?  (Sorry, I'm probably using the wrong terms.)  For example, a complete URL for a query is host:port/solr/core/select?q=getrichquick%0A&wt=json&indent=true .  What would I need to put in the URL after after /update to send solr {"id":"change.me","title":"change.me"} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [UpdateJSON page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) for a description of the update format for sending documents to Solr in a JSON based format (ignore the /json part of the URL, as this was for older versions of Solr).

An example from that page:

```
curl $URL -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
  {
    "id" : "MyTestDocument",
    "title" : "This is just a test"
  }
]'
```

For very short update requests you can also submit the update through a `GET` request using `stream.body`:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=...
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the great input from @MatsLindh
this worked for me:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?stream.body={"add":{"doc":{"id":"DOC1","name":"DOC1"}},"commit":{}}
```